# Is it possible to keep both my development site and my live site on the same host?

Tags: web-hosting

I have a Facebook app that resides on two hosts. The development app resides on one host, and the live app resides on another. Because there are two hosts involved I am paying two hosting fees.

My question is this: is it possible to put both the development app and the live app on the same host? If it is possible, can anyone tell me what is required in regards to software configuration, development environment, version control, etc. to make this work? (a link would be very helpful)

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: This question may be more suitable for stackoverflow or serverfault. It's asking about configuration of a server system, which would lean me towards serverfault, but also deals with programming stuff (IDEs, version control, etc.) which is more in stack overflow's area. I have not voted to move yet, but it may warrant moving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what sort of setup you have, but I don't see any technical reason why you couldn't.

- Software configuration: not sure exactly what you mean by this, but if you're using Apache/PHP/MySQL (assuming this since a lot of facebook apps use PHP), you should be able to use the same configuration for all of them. You would want to create separate databases for the live and development versions, but other than that, the setup should be straightforward.
- Development environment: again, we don't know anything about your development environment, but it should be easy enough to just set up your development tools to target the testing site, and only move code over to the production site once it's ready to go.
- Version control: set it up the way you normally would, just have the live and testing sites be separate projects/directories/solutions/whatever your version control system calls it.

As a general strategy, I would have your development site be a separate subdomain on your main site, so have the live app be at `example.com` and the testing/development app be at `dev.example.com` or some such. Set up two different databases, one for the live app and one for testing, and point all your development tools at the testing copy.

It's hard to give you any more specific info without knowing more about the environment you're working in. What languages, software, etc. are you using, who is your current host, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, depending on your platform, check these for examples if you are using Apache:

- http://trevordavis.net/blog/creating-multiple-sites-on-a-local-web-server/
- http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/412
- http://drupal.org/node/365844
- http://drupal.org/node/32715
- http://ailoo.net/2008/07/set-up-multiple-virtual-hosts-on-xampp-for-windows/

Hope this helps.